# iBeacons: understanding minor, major and UUID

Tags: iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins, ibeacon

I can't seem to figure out the relevance or importance of major and minor values in detecting iBeacons. When I register and configure my Gimbal beacon, I give it a specific set of values for UUID, major and minor, and then when I use my cordova iBeacon plugin I can detect my beacons but only if I instruct it to look for these exact parameters.

It would seem to me that only the uuid would be critical to detecting beacons. Yet they aren't detected by my app unless I match value for value each of those 3 criteria

Can anyone elucidate the relevance of the major and minor values in beacon detection and is it true that my code needs to specifically instruct the plugin to look for beacons matching all these values.

Hope this post makes sense... the iBeacon detection has so many moving parts that learning about it has tied my brain in a pretzel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The iBeacon protocol was implemented this way to ensure that each beacon would be unique. If you have a large beacon deployment (lets say in all of your stores across the country) Then you want to set the identifiers in such a way that you can id the beacons individually. An example deployment would look like this:

All beacon UUIDS: 1234...

All department stores in Boston: Major = 1
All department stores in Chicago: Major = 2

Minor can vary by aisle or section.

So then I know if I detect beacon UUID 1234..., Major 1 Minor 8 I can map it to the Boston store clothing section. This is just an example (and a kind of lame on at that) but essentially the levels of identifiers are just a greater insurance that the beacon you detect is the one you actually want.

When monitoring for iBeacons you can actually monitor at each of the different identifier levels, so you could monitor for all beacons with a UUID, all beacons with a UUID and Major, or all beacons with a UUID, Major, and Minor (which ideally would just be a single beacon)

Comment: Got it - thanks. So thats why the major and minor are optional.

Comment: Ya its all about levels of specificity. In the above example, you'd probably want to scan for the UUID until you hit a major, then you'd know what city you were in, then start looking for UUID and major, then you'd start getting the specific beacons, then go back to UUID monitoring when you exited all those beacons

Answer (score 6):

This statement is critical:

> It would seem to me that only the uuid would be critical to detecting beacons. Yet they aren't detected by my app unless I match value for value each of those 3 criteria

Using raw iOS APIs and the Android Beacon Library, supplying only the UUID will match beacons.  **You do not need to specify the major and minor to detect beacons.**  The fact that you are seeing otherwise means something is wrong with the code you are running, the framework it is using, or both.

The purpose of the major and minor are to subdivide the identifier space for logical purposes.  If you then match solely on UUID or UUID and major, you can take diffrent actions depending on which beacon is detected by examining the minor value.

Comment: I was specifying values in my code thinking it was some kind of range...  and only having success when I would match the values I was searching for. At this point I am only trying to detect and react to hardcoded values before I build out the dynamic aspect.  I hadn't tried omitting values yet, now I understand their purpose.

Comment: What if I do not know the uuid of my beacon?

Comment: If you do not know the UUID, you cannot use iOS APIs to detect it. On Android, you can.  If you only care about android, just leave the UUID null in your region definition and it will match all beacons.  If you do care about iOS, you must supply the UUID or it won't work.  If you simply need to figure out your UUID, use an Android device with an off the shelf beacon scanner to scan the beacon and find the UUID.